# RxSwift: MVVM Update Struct on View Model and Trigger Table Update on View Controller

Tags: json, swift, asynchronous, tableview, rx-swift

I am currently diving into RxSwift and I am trying to use it to update a TableView on a ViewController(.xib) with data that I get from a JSON and is encoded into a struct with Codable.

Here's my VM atm:

```
import Foundation
import RxCocoa
import RxSwift

protocol MenuViewModelProtocol {
    func viewDidLoad()
}

class MenuViewModel: MenuViewModelProtocol {

    private (set) var menu = MenuModel()
    private let menuIntermediary = MenuDataIntermediary()

    func viewDidLoad() {
        debugPrint("MenuViewModel.viewDidLoad: Async request for menu was made")
        requestAndSetMenuToIntermediary { (_ success) in
            switch success {
            case true:
                debugPrint("MenuViewModel.requestAndSetMenuToIntermediary: Did get Menu successfully")
                // print(self.menu) // -> menu is here
            case false:
                debugPrint("MenuViewModel.requestAndSetMenuToIntermediary: Did not get Menu successfully")
            }
        }
    }

    private func requestAndSetMenuToIntermediary(completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
        menuIntermediary.jsonDataToMenuConversion { [weak self] (success) in
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    debugPrint("MenuViewModel.requestMenuToIntermediary: couldn't create a strong self reference")
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }

                guard let menu = menu else {
                    debugPrint("MenuViewModel.requestMenuToIntermediary: couldn't unwrap menu data")
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }
                strongSelf.menu = menu

                // print(strongSelf.menu) // -> menu is here
                completion(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The flow behing *requestAndSetMenuToIntermediary* is in short:

-> DataManager requests JSON from URL and returns a Data?

-> Intermediary Layer parses the JSON onto a Struct (with nested structs) using Codable and returns a Struct?

-> ViewModel gets the Struct? and unwraps it, being it ready for UI setup.

-> ??

My problem at '??' is to notify the VC that **menu** was updated in order to setup the TableView. Any suggestions? I've tried using PublishSubjects, BehaviorSubject combined with observables but I can't seem to make it work. I'm in doubt if it is syntax or something related to the background flow...

Thanks in advance! 
P.s - If more info is needed I can happily provide it, I was just trying to not make a very long post :p

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't compile I can't tell if `menu` is supposed to be a `MenuModel?` or a `MenuModel`. If I make it non-optional, then your `guard let menu = menu` fails to compile because you can't unwrap a non-optional and if I make it optional, then that same line fails because `self` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not find any code about data binding in your code. Normally, if you are using RxSwift, you should create a data sequence and bound to your view. For Table View or Collection View, we love using [RxDataSource](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources)

1. Create an `Observable` getting response from server
2. Using `map` to Transform the data
3. bind the data to your view

In you case, you should define a function to get menu model from server

```
private func getMenuModel() -> Obserable<MenuModel> {
   /* the code getting response from server and transform to menu model */
}
```

Declare an Observable

```
let menuModelObservable: Observable<MenuModel>

init() {
   menuModelObservable = getMenuModel()
}
```

Bind the data to your `TableView`

```
/* Your ViewController*/

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let viewModel = MenuViewModel()
    viewModel.menuModelObservable.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell")) { index, model, cell in
      cell.textLabel?.text = model
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In fact, I don't have any Rx related code in the snippet per choice because it was a bit of a mess since I tried using PublishSubjects and ObjectRelays/ObjectSubject, amongst other shannanigans with no success.

I will try this and get back to you soon :)